# Attach matrix to inside of matrix in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Suppose there are 4D matrix (3,4,6,1) and 2D array (6,4) , I want to attach the 2D array left side of 2D matrix[0:3][0:4].

I can only do this problem using for loop.

```
for i in range(0, cols):
   for j in range(0, rows):  
       x = np.append(a[i][j], b, axis = 1)
```

I try to make 2D -> 4D and use np.append ,but still don't know how to make 2D-> 4D like (3,4,6,4).

Comment: what's this `np.attach` you're using? my `numpy` doesn't have it

Comment: Ops sorry it is np.append

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly one simple way would be

```
out = np.empty((3, 4, 6, 5))
out[..., :1] = a
out[..., 1:] = b
```